# Trouble with graphing a function with chartjs

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, linechart

I'm trying to graph a function with chartjs but I have some troubles

I don't know why xAxis labels have all these digits.

is There a better approach I should take ? because I think this code is not good

how can I make the highest value of the graph be on the yAxis label?

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const xAxis = []
for(let i = 0; i < 1 ; i=i+0.001){
  xAxis.push(i)
}
const yAxis = []
for(let i = 0 ; i < xAxis.length;i++){
  yAxis.push(1225*Math.pow(xAxis[i],48)*Math.pow((1-xAxis[i]),2))
}
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: xAxis,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'F(x)',
        data: yAxis,
        borderWidth: 1,
                fill: false,
        pointRadius: 0
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        x:{
          ticks:{
            beginAtZero : true,
            //maxTicksLimit : 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SRstyle.css">
    <title>Success Rate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>



      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
      <script src="SRscript.js"></script>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, for line chart, the X axis is a "category" axis therefore is expecting labels as strings. And the strings representations of the numbers are the values you are setting.

Change the X axis configuration as following which should fix it:

```
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
    x:{
      type: 'linear', // <-- add this one
      beginAtZero : true, // <-- axis option, not ticks one
      ticks:{
        //maxTicksLimit : 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Be also aware that `beginAtZero` option is an axis option and not a ticks one therefore you should move it at upper level.

Comment: thank you so much .
is there any way to mark the highest value and it's corresponding x value on the graph ?

Comment: Well, you have some options. The first is setting the "major" options: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#major-tick-configuration but you need to implement the scriptable options which can highlight the tick as you like. for X axis, you need to do something similar, without setting major but changing L&F of the ticks where the major of Y axis is set

Comment: If you share here how you would like to mark the major and if I have time, I can try to show you something... But I need time

Comment: Have a look to codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/WNaGLdY It's leveraging on datalabels plugin